# Simplified trajectory equation to identify Time Taken(t) by a protectile to travel Distance(d), under gravity?

Tags: opengl, android, game-mechanics, projectile-physics, trajectory

I am building a game, where I have to plot a trajectory of a ball in 3D space, launched with an inital velocity **Sx, Sy, Sz**. [*I am using OpenGL and Android-NDK*]

> Lets assume **Sz** is always **0**. And **Sx** and **Sy** values are known.

Now, I am able to plot a dotted trajectory properly along the path taken by the ball, under uniform gravity. But, the problem is that the distance between the points are NOT EQUIDISTANT, since I am plotting them at regular time intervals.

So, the next step for me is to plot the trajectory at intervals (**tn**) such that my distance traveled (**d**) is always fixed.

> Now, assume I want to plot the **"nth"** trajectory point for every **"d"** units of distance. So, I need **'tn'** to plot it.

I have tried solving this on white board, but the resulting equation for **'tn'** is too complex. And I could get this far :

> **d^2 = dx^2 + dy^2;**
>
> **dx = Sx * t;  |  t = dx/Sx;**
>
> **dy = Sy * t + 1/2 (g) (t^2); | dy = Sy * (dx/Sx) + 1/2 (g) ((dx/Sx)^2);**
>
> So **t = 'gives me an equation that has a highest order of 4'**;

I am hoping there must be a better way. Can anyone please help me derive a better equation for **'t'**.

> Time **(tn)** = ?; 
>      Assume **tn = Tn - T(n-1)**; 
>      Where **'Tn'** is total time to cover **'n'** times **'d'** units of distance.
>
> In terms of :
>               **'d'** : is distance interval. (fixed);
>               **'sx'**: initial velocity along x axis (horizotal ground);
>               **'sy'**: initial velocity along y axis (against gravity **'g'**);

Hope, I made thing clear enough. Please let me know if you need more information.

I tried this question in 'physics.stackexchange.com', but I was thinking this might be a more appropriate place to discuss, since I want a perspective of a game developers too.

Comment: Looks like you need the famous arc-length parameterization of a curve.. http://math.colorado.edu/~angele/calc3-fa08/lec/Lecture10/Lecture10hand.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Or, if you don't mind a slightly less pure, but much simpler and good-enough-for-visualisation approach:

Use an approximation to the arc, by connecting points on it with straight lines. Calculating points on this path that are equidistantly spaced should be relatively trivial.

Comment: +1 for this idea.. since, at least visually, it should be more pleasing since the user doesn't see the intermediate (non-linear) parabola arcs and cannot judge their actual length. All the user has to do is to compute the intersection of a parabola with a sphere, where the center of that sphere is in one of those trajectory dots. More maths..

Comment: Yup, I tried this approach! Its the way my current plotting happens. :-) The problem here is that my "draw_frame" from the gameloop is not guaranteed to be called at a fixed interval and the interpolated points seem a little off when the density of points increase. This happens when the ball is launched with high initial velocities.

However, I might be able to tune it a little more by some trial and error. I will give it another shot. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's try it in 3D:

Assume the dynamics equation: **r(t) = r0 + v0 * t + 0.5*g* t^2** where *r* is the position vector, *v0* is the initial launch velocity and *g* is the gravitational constant acceleration vector *(0,0,-9.8)* .

Now let's analyze the length functional: **L(t) = Integral(0,t, ||r'(t)|| dt)** . This means that the total curve length from its beginning (t=0) till this *t* time instance is *L(t)*. In this formula, **||r'(t)||** is the norm of the time derivative of the position function **r(t)**. We know that the norm is actually the square root of the dot product of its argument vector:

**||r'(t)|| = sqrt(dot(r'(t),r'(t))** hence you can analyze this amount:

**r'(t) = v0 + g * t** and therefore **dot(r'(t),r'(t))** = **v0ov0 + 2*v0og*t + gog*t^2** where `o` is the dot product operator (some write it as an angular bracket < a , b >, others use a dot which I tried to imitate here with this `o`). This dot product, in your case, is a quadratic function of `t` with nothing more than scalar coefficients in the name of those dot products. Hence, if you can compute a primitive for this **sqrt(dot(r'(t),r'(t))=sqrt(at^2 + bt + c)** where  **a=gog**, **b=2v0og**, **c=v0ov0** you're on the right path.

Call this primitive **F(t)**, then **L(t) = F(t) - F(0)**. If you want to know what *t0* instance corresponds to a length on your path of *d0* units, then just compute the inverse of *L(t)* by, what else, computing the inverse function of **F(t)**.

as I am in a hurry, I can't compute the primitive, nor its inverse for you, but if you can't either, do it numerically (numerical integration and then numerical equation solving via Newton's method).

*Later edit:*
Use the [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral%20of%20sqrt%28ax%5E2%20%2b%20bx%20%2b%20c%29) to find  the integral, then perhaps solve numerically for its inverse..
or again [Wolfra Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Inverse+of+Integral+of+sqrt%28ax%5E2+%2B+bx+%2B+c%29&dataset=)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I understood your concept. :-) I am working on it. Will get back once I get to solve it. 

Cheers!